# Import specific data from renewed to multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have searched through, but I can't find the solution, although I believe it should be here. Perhaps, keywords I am using to search are not correct.

Problem:

I want to import (capture) data that refers to Region A from spreadsheet table named "New Data". The table is renewed every 2 work days.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WRFvZ5XXpf06WPgC70KRtGi5_hmGKZXFiFYcW806_uk/edit?usp=drivesdk)

and add these new row to spreadsheet named Region A which already has it's own data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_SBGjUNOr2Oi2tpCVlmD0e1x1Ov52khJYN5jcm8Mf8/edit?usp=drivesdk

What I tried:

Importrange function works good, but it is not enough. I have to open the Region A Spreadsheet and write the function at the end of the table, then copy paste the results also for all Spreadsheet documents of 6 Regions as in the example (in real life the are around 50). And then in 2 days to grab the renewe data from "New Data" table and copypaste it.

Is there a way to apply a script that would add rows (from New Data to Region A table) to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Update 26.12.2016: Please see my comments below, I can't solve one problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear but it sounds like you what to query the data for each region, so for region A try:

```
 =query(IMPORTRANGE("1WRFvZ5XXpf06WPgC70KRtGi5_hmGKZXFiFYcW806_uk","Sheet Name!A1:D"),"where Col1 contains 'Region A'")
```

just change Sheet Name! above

**EDIT #2**

Based on comments asking not to append row:

```
function regionA() {
  // Data Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Code for Region A
  var regionAId = ""
  var regionA = "Region A";
  var regionAdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionAId).getSheets()[0];
  var column = regionAdata.getRange('A2:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var ct = 1;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }

  for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == regionA){
      regionAdata.getRange(ct+2,1,1,4).setValues([data[i].slice(0, 4)]);
      ct++
    } 
  }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

Appending a row

Based on your comments you can use this script in your newData file not your report files.

```
  function myFunction() {
  // Data Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //You can change these for each Region
  var regionAId = "SPREADSHEET KEY for RegionA"
  var regionA = "Region A";
  var regionAdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionAId);
  var regionBId = "SPREADSHEET KEY for RegionB"
  var regionB = "Region B";
  var regionBdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionBId);
  //add the other regions

  for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == regionA){
      regionAdata.appendRow(data[i])
    }     
    if (data[i][0] == regionB){
      regionBdata.appendRow(data[i])
    }    
    //add the other regions
  }
}
```

It's not that clean because I did it quickly but follow the pattern to add the other regions and everything will be done at once.

Comment: I try to explain better. Lets say I have 50 Spreadsheets for each region with it's own older data and one Spreadsheet that has new data. I place and rewrite new data in Spreadsheet 3 times a week.

If I use query&Importrange it would grab the current data from "new data" according to Region, but:

1) I need to copy-pasted (to be able to edit l) 2) I need to be able to importrange again new data that will appear in New Data spreadsheet.

So, I need importrange + copypaste the imported results + importrange again when new data is replaced in New Data spreadsheet, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Works Perfect if I insert the script to all spreadsheet lists. And the final tone: is it possible to run the script at once on all the lists?

Comment: Or of it is not possible, is there a way to make 6 scripts for "New Data" spreadsheet that would send the data to these "Region" spreadsheets? Thank you

Comment: Alright, I found the added lines in bottom of the report document. It is because there are formulas in the right side of the document and they end up in the bottom. Is it possible to make the script look up columns A-M to check whether the rows are filled? Thanks again

Comment: I substituted data [i] [0] to data [i] [1] and now it checks up column 2 for region check. But how to make add the new lines under older ones (ignoring the formulas on the right side of the doc) I can't figure out.

Comment: So, it all happened when I applied the script to real spreadsheet that has formulas starting Q column.

Comment: see edit #2.  If this solves your issue please accept the answer.