# Import specific ranged data (only of columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Many thanks to [@utphx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5736988/utphx) here who wrote [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41313534). I accepted the answer and then ran into a problem when testing the script in real documents.

The document that [has the script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WRFvZ5XXpf06WPgC70KRtGi5_hmGKZXFiFYcW806_uk/edit?usp=drivesdk) sends the split data from it's list to report files spreadheets (Region A, Region B). The script places the new data under the old one for each of the [region](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_SBGjUNOr2Oi2tpCVlmD0e1x1Ov52khJYN5jcm8Mf8/edit?usp=drivesdk) (Region A).

However, the Region A receives new rows and places it not under old ones, but in the end of the list (please see the Region A file) because document contains formulas in column G.

How is it possible to correct the script so that it sends and receives data only to Columns A-D and igonres the formulas to the right?

```js
  function myFunction() {
    // Data Sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    //You can change these for each Region
    var regionAId = "SPREADSHEET KEY for RegionA"
    var regionA = "Region A";
    var regionAdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionAId);
    var regionBId = "SPREADSHEET KEY for RegionB"
    var regionB = "Region B";
    var regionBdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionBId);
    //add the other regions

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == regionA){
            regionAdata.appendRow(data[i])
        }     
        if (data[i][0] == regionB){
            regionBdata.appendRow(data[i])
        }    
        //add the other regions
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41313534/7337152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be posting a separate question in regards to your initial question but here is the code that should work for Region A.  You can extend for the other regions.  It seems like you are in a rush so this code is quick and not efficient but should work:

```
function regionA() {
  // Data Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Code for Region A
  var regionAId = ""
  var regionA = "Region A";
  var regionAdata = SpreadsheetApp.openById(regionAId).getSheets()[0];
  var column = regionAdata.getRange('A2:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); 
  var ct = 1;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }

  for ( var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == regionA){
      regionAdata.getRange(ct+2,1,1,4).setValues([data[i].slice(0, 4)]);
      ct++
    } 
  }
}
```